# implementing Gram-Schmidt process using SageMaths

Tags: sagemath

I'm trying to implement a function myGramSchmidt(L), which takes a list L of vectors living in some inner product space, and returns a new list which has implemented the Gram-Schmidt process above.

(UPDATE) My code:

```
def myGramSchmidt(L):
    
    n = len(L)
    V = L.copy()
    for j in range(n):
        for i in range(j):
            V[j] -= ip(V[i],V[j]) * V[i]
        V[j]= V[j]/V[j].norm() #normalised vector
        print(V[j])
    print(ip(V[0],V[0]))
    print(ip(V[1],V[1]))
    print(ip(V[2],V[2]))
    return V

B=Matrix(QQ,3,3,[1,0,0, 0,2,0, 0,0,3])
V3 = VectorSpace(QQ, 3, inner_product_matrix = B)

v1 = V3(vector(random_matrix(QQ,1,3)))
v2 = V3(vector(random_matrix(QQ,1,3)))
v3 = V3(vector(random_matrix(QQ,1,3)))


L = [v1,v2,v3]
M1=Matrix(QQ,3,3,L)
pretty_print(M1)
myGramSchmidt(L)
```

I have generated matrix:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2}&0&-1 \\
2&-1&-1 \\
0&1&0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
with output:

```
(1/5*sqrt(5), 0, -2/5*sqrt(5))
(1/15*sqrt(6), -1/6*sqrt(6), 11/30*sqrt(6))
(2/15, 2/3, 11/15)

13/5
139/50
63/25
```

As you can see, the vectors are normalised, however the inner product of two same vectors does not equal to 1?

Comment: The inner product of distinct vectors should be $0$, not $1$, shouldn't it? Can you provide sample input that produces the wrong output? Also, is `ip` the inner product?

Comment: yes `ip` is the inner product: `def ip(v,w):
    return v.inner_product(w)`

Answer (score 0):

The expected output should be: a list of vectors satisfying `v.inner_product(v) == 1` and `v.inner_product(w) == 0` when `v` and `w` are distinct.

You should interchange lines in your code: change

```
    V[j]= V[j]/V[j].norm() #normalised vector
    for i in range(j):
        V[j] -= ip(V[i],V[j]) * V[i]
```

to

```
    for i in range(j):
        V[j] -= ip(V[i],V[j]) * V[i]
     V[j]= V[j]/V[j].norm() #normalised vector
```

(Don't normalize the vector until you've done all other modifications to it.)

Edit: a further problem is the `norm` method, which seems to ignore the inner product matrix. Try this instead:

```
    for i in range(j):
        V[j] -= ip(V[i],V[j]) * V[i]
     V[j]= V[j]/sqrt(V[j].inner_product(V[j])) #normalised vector
```

You can also add this as a check:

```
M = matrix(n, [V[i].inner_product(V[j]) for i in range(n) for j in range(n)])
print(M)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help :) Please see the edited question, actually after the change, the function have the same issue as before.

Comment: The problem is that the `norm` method ignores `inner_product_matrix`.

Comment: Thank you, I 'sort of' resolved the code :)

Comment: My last edit, using `sqrt(...inner_product(...))`, didn't work? It works for me.